# Can a model be a frontend and backend model Magento?

Tags: php, apache, magento

Just a simple question. The data is suppose to be protected but I need implement my object into the product EAV after the products load so I can have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

In the config.xml of a module, the model classes of that module are defined.
If the model is only accessible from backend, or frontend, or both, depends on which tag you use.

If you want them to be accessible from both frontend and backend, use `global` tag

```
<global>
        <models>
            <module_tag>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
            </module_tag>
        <models>
<global>
```